# Adding More Parameters For Particular Virtual Method

Tags: c++, class, vector, overriding, abstract

Hello I have a collection of Classes which are derived from the base Class.
All the Classes use a method which I have set up to be a virtual void like this.

```
virtual void do_method(cPlayer&, cPlayer&) = 0;
```

However for **One** particular class I would like to use the same do_method for that class but I would like it to have an another parameter which would be a vector of pointers for example.

```
virtual void do_method(cPlayer&, cPlayer&, vector<cBase*>);
```

Is there a way to do this without the Override feature as I am not using the most recent version of C++ and this is what I came across when researching.

Comment: How can it both be "the same" method, and have another parameter at the same time?

Comment: @jtbandes You are saying I should just create a new do_method with the three parameters? And leave the do_method with two parameters for that one blank?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to *call* the virtual function through your altered one, something like:

```
void do_method(cPlayer& p1, vector<cBase*>& v) {
    for (auto p: v)
         do_method(p1, *p);
}
```